# How to display result in the same line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, view, styling

How should I do if I want those `ProductName` in the same line in view. I mean without new line for each product.

This kind of way I get them every name in new line, But I want them in the same line.

```
<div class="col-md-12">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <div class="col-md-1">
        @Html.ActionLink(item.ProductName, "PrName", "Products", new { Id = item.ProductId }, null)
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You could add a style to your `col-md-1` class like `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: This is a styling question more than a c# one, I suggest looking at bootstrap classes, as I can see you're already using it with `col-md-*` or adding css styling to your page.

Comment: currently with the `col-md-1` depending on screen size, but at most only 12 products will show on one line. Adding to @itsme86 you might need some custom css to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: @itsme86 thank you it's working, but they are so tite with eachother, how can I make space between them? I changed to col-md-2 but the same result.

Comment: @JonasWillander add a padding to your `div` as well.

Comment: Try changing <div class="col-md-12"> to <div class="form-row">. This will give spacing between the col. Or you can use class="row" for more space.

Answer (score 2):

Remove div tag inside your for loop.

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(item.ProductName, "PrName", "Products", new { Id = item.ProductId }, null)
        }
```

This works out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using  tag inside your for loop, which is rendering you division as many time as for loop. So remove your  tag inside the for loop. Your code must look something similar like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(item.ProductName, "PrName", "Products", new { Id = item.ProductId }, null)
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but since the div element is used that means your elements will be block-element.
Instead of div try to use span. 
Hope that helps.